# Regroup continuous attrbutes per chunk of time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to regroup by the largest chunk of time of continuous attributes (meaning that attribute_1 and attribute_2 both stay the same).

Please note that there could be N attributes, and that a vectorized solution would be the best since the datasets may be quite big.

For example, here is my input :

```
    start_date  end_date    attribute_1 attribute_2
0   2020-01-01  2020-02-01  A           1
1   2020-02-01  2020-03-01  A           1
2   2020-03-01  2020-04-01  B           1
3   2020-04-01  2020-05-01  A           1
4   2020-05-01  2020-06-01  A           1
5   2020-06-01  2020-07-01  A           2
```

And here is the dataframe I want to obtain :

```
    start_date  end_date    attribute_1 attribute_2
0   2020-01-01  2020-03-01  A           1
1   2020-03-01  2020-04-01  B           1
2   2020-04-01  2020-06-01  A           1
3   2020-06-01  2020-07-01  A           2
```

In order to reproduce the input example, you can use the following :

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
start_dates = pd.date_range(start=datetime(2020, 1, 1), end=datetime(2020, 6, 1), freq="MS", inclusive="both")
end_dates = pd.date_range(start=datetime(2020, 2, 1), end=datetime(2020, 7, 1), freq="MS", inclusive="both")
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "start_date": start_dates,
    "end_date": end_dates,
    "attribute_1": ["A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A"],
    "attribute_2": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
})
```

Comment: and if one of attributes is not the "same": `["A", "A", "A"], [1, 2, 1]` ? what should be the result in that case?

Comment: Updated the example, hope this answers @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to make a group.

```
att = ['attribute_1', 'attribute_2']

grp = (df[att].ne(df[att].shift()) 
       .any(axis=1)
       .astype(int)
       .cumsum())
```

Then use this `grp` to group by and aggregate.

```
# Python >= 3.9
df = (df.groupby(grp)
      .agg({'start_date': 'min', 'end_date': 'max'} | {x: 'max' for x in att}))

# Python < 3.9
df = (df.groupby(grp)
      .agg({**{'start_date': 'min', 'end_date': 'max'}, **{x: 'max' for x in att}}))
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to assign a new column, you could also pass the grouping Series directly to `groupby` ;)

Comment: oh yeah, that's true.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. Didn't know about *.ne*, very useful !